# Null Pointer Exception when creation a fragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am creating fragments inside fragment but I got `NullPointerException`. I don't know why the same code is working in the class which extends the `FragmentActivity` but it's not working here in class which extends `Fragment`. Following is my code,

```
public class SecondLevel extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlevel, container, false);

        btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button11);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

   ...
   ...
   ...
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fr1 = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button11:
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Button 1 is clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fr1 = new ThirdFragment();
            FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm1.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
           .....
```

Now in the ThirdFragment what I am doing is as follows:

```
 package com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("F1", "F1");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.thirdlevel, container, false);
}
}
```

Note that I have imported the same support libraries so it's not that problem.

Its my xml thirdlevel:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonlevel3"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Its my secondlevel xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/laSecond"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Level 1" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button11"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Level 2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button22"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView33"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Level 3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView44"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Level 4" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button44"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button 4" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842): java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.SecondLevel.onClick(SecondLevel.java:50) 
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549) 
E/AndroidRuntime(19842): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393) 
E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: Can you also post you `second_level.xml` layout? I have a feeling it doesn't contain `fragment_place` element..

Comment: try to fragmentTransaction.add instead for fragmentTransaction.replace.

Comment: how can i comment its saying its too long

Comment: its not working either @jay

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(19842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.SecondLevel.onClick(SecondLevel.java:50)
03-07 10:58:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(19842):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
E/AndroidRuntime(19842): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime(19842):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Comment: Post your **secondlevel.xml** file

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi At which line you got this error? Show me that.

Comment: FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm1.beginTransaction();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this from

```
FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to

```
FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thanks although i tried it first but i dont know it wont work before for me now its working thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your wel come.. Glad to help you!!